# How to generate coordinates to represent a circle in 3D programming?

Tags: javascript, 3d

Lets say I have 10 objects. The first object is placed at x75, y0, z0. Now lets say I wanted to orient the objects so they form a circle with x0, y0, z0 at it's center. And each object is an equal distance from each other. Is there a formula I can use to generate the coordinates? I should mention the number of objects wont always be 10. It's a variable so some times it might be 15 or 20 or any other number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some formula like:

```
x = x0 + r * cos(theta * pi / 180);
y = y0 + r * sin(theta * pi / 180);
```

so `x0 = 0` and `y0 = 0`.
For `theta`, it will be the degree, which depends on the number of objects. So if you have 10 objects, `theta` will be a multiple of `36`. So basically it is a multiple of `360/num of objects`.
`r` is the radius of the circle, so if the first one is at `(75, 0, 0)`, then `r = 75`.

Comment: Cool. I wanted to keep the height of the objects the same. So should I  just substitute y for z? Also just to double check if I wanted to have  15 objects theta would be 360/15=24?

Comment: Also I'm kinda confused by x0 and y0

Comment: It is basically the coordinate of the origins. So if the origins is at `(0,0,0)`, then `x0 = 0`, `y0 = 0` and `z = z0`. `x`, `y`, and `z` are the coordinates that we are looking for.

Yes if you have 15 objects, then it will be 24. You can substitute y for z if you want all the objects to have the same height.